# dtype in numpy 1.9.1 broken?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

After recently updating my various python packages (I'm now running python 2.7.9 with numpy 1.9.1 and matplotlib 1.4.3) a number of my own programs seem to be broken. I am using the mlab record array operations in several places and I keep getting errors of the type "data type not understood". It seems like the `csv2rec` function now returns record names as unicode rather than ASCII which causes problems in the mlab-routines. I traced the problem back to the `numpy.dtype` function where it appears that the operation

`np.dtype([(u'a',np.float),(u'b',np.float)])`

generates an error while

`np.dtype({'names':[u'a',u'b'],'formats':[np.float,np.float]})`

works fine.

For now I replaced the calls to `np.dtype` in mlab.py by a wrapper function that uses the second form above, but I don't think this is a terribly sustainable solution. Is there a deeper reason in `numpy` why this problem occurs and why are the field names now unicode anyway?

Comment: Can you put in a PR to matplotlib with that fix?  The issue is that we switched to using unicode literals in 1.4.0.

Comment: At this point it's really not a fix but more a dirty hack. It seems like the issue also causes problems in other places (e.g., generating an mrecord view) so I'm not sure this is something to be addressed from within matplotlib or rather at the numpy level. But I'm lacking the insight here to fix this properly.

Comment: If not a PR, than an issue so it does not get lost.

Comment: OK, I'll do that. Thanks!

Comment: I just saw that the topic is being discussed in the numpy community: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2407